# "The path .. would result in a file outside the App Bundle and cannot be used" Error, mono touch / Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

i am currently facing a really weird and annoying error message after migrating my Xamarin.IOS - Project to the 64bit unified - API. The exact error message is:

```
   /Users/falcowinkler/Dev/AHK_App -Kopie/AHK_App_iOS/../ahk_app_ios/resources/.DS_Store: 
Error: The path   '../ahk_app_ios/resources/.DS_Store' would result 
in a file outside of the app bundle and cannot be used. (AHK_App_iOS).
```

I get that error not only for .DS_Store but also for two other files. 
Here are the things i tried.

- Clean / Rebuild
- delete bin / obj Folder and rebuild
- I deleted the files that throw the error, just to get another message that the project is missing these files. I added them again after that, and got the same error as above again
- I tried moving my project to other locations, but the error does not change in the slightest.
- I tried to remove all problematic files, before migrating, which didn't work as well.

Does anybody know where all the file references are stored in Xamarin, so i can view/edit them to find out what the error is?

I mean the DS_Store file is just a tiny file from mac - finder architecture, is not even necessary for my project, but still it is referencing it, i will just have to kick out these references i guess.

If anybody encountered these issues as well, and has a solution, pls leave a quick post here, thanks :)

**Update**
I am now pretty sure that there are some misplaced references to files in my project, i saw a similar issue on git hub. But how can i wipe them out? I tried removing my entire resources Folder and adding it again, but it didn't help either. Error message now looks as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: 
Error:   Bundle Resource '../ahk_app_ios/resources/.DS_Store' 
not found on disk (should be at '/Users/falcowinkler/Documents/AHKKopie/ahk_app_ios/resources/.DS_Store') (AHK_App_iOS)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, just search your project files for the filename. The .csproj File will appear, where you will be able to wipe out the reference to the file, causing the problem.

Comment: This mostly solved it for me.  I opened the .csproj file in another application and was able to fix the path for the files that threw the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin Studio, you can delete the .DS_Store under your Ios project [ProjectName.iOS] under the Resources folder